# mysql_num_rows() php - is it efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysql-num-rows

I have several `SELECT` statements on a PHP page, and I used Dreamweaver to generate those.

After going through the code it generated, there seemed to be alot of fluff which I could cut out under most circumstances, a `mysql_num_rows()` line for each statement being an example.

So I'm wondering if anyone can tell me whether or not this actually saves resources - considering the query is being run regardless, is there any actual overhead for this?

---

UPDATE:
After following Chriszuma's suggestion about microtime, here are my results:

```
//time before running the query
1: 0.46837500 1316102620

//time after the query ran
2: 0.53913800 1316102620

//time before calling mysql_num_rows()
3: 0.53914200 1316102620

//time after mysql_num_rows()
4: 0.53914500 1316102620
```

So not much overhead at all, it seems

Comment: There is always overhead on a function call in PHP, but it is usually minimal, unless your calling it hundreds of thousands of times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that such a call would have an extremely minimal impact on performance. It is just counting the rows of its internally-stored query result. The SQL query itself is going to take the vast majority of processing time.

If you want to know for sure, you can execute [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) before and after the call to see exactly how long it is taking.

```
$startTime = microtime(true);
mysql_num_rows();
$time = microtime(true) - $startTime;
echo("mysql_num_rows() execution: $time seconds\n");
```

My suspicion is that you will see something in the microseconds range.

Comment: this worked although i did a quick and dirty test while you were writing the code so just called microtime() by itself each time :)

Answer (score 4):

mysql_num_rows() counts rows *after* they have been fetched.  It's like you fetched all rows and stored them in a PHP array, and then ran `count($array)`.  But mysql_num_rows() is implemented in C within the MySQL client library, so it should be a bit more efficient than the equivalent PHP code.

Note that in order for mysql_num_rows() to work, you do have to have the complete result of your query in PHP's memory space.  So there is overhead in the sense that a query result set could be large, and take up a lot of memory.

Comment: +1 That's why `mysql_num_rows` won't work when you use [mysql_unbuffered_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php)